# Start/Stop VMs during off-hours - Azure

Tags: shutdown-script

Need your help to find a runbook/automation script through which I could start/stop the VM's in Azure at a specific schedule & then in case we have to delay the shutdown schedule for a particular VM, it allows us to do so. Ideally, it should notify the end user, VM is going to shutdown in 30 min or so & gives option to delay the shutdown if need be.

Is there any existing runbook available in runbook gallary within automation account? Can anyone please advise or confirm?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this by creating power shell runbook . This is for Starting VM for working hours. you can attached this to schedule inside workbook as required.

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] 
    [String]  $AzureConnectionAssetName = 'AzureRunAsConnection',

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] 
    [String] $ResourceGroupName = 'Your-VM-RG'
)

#Check for Weekends
$dayOfWeek = (Get-Date).DayOfWeek

if($dayOfWeek -eq 'Saturday' -or $dayOfWeek -eq 'Sunday'){
    exit
}

# Get the connection
$Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $AzureConnectionAssetName -ErrorAction Stop     

$null = Add-AzureRmAccount `
    -ServicePrincipal `
    -TenantId $Conn.TenantId `
    -ApplicationId $Conn.ApplicationId `
    -CertificateThumbprint $Conn.CertificateThumbprint `
    -ErrorAction Stop `
    -ErrorVariable err

if($err) {
    throw $err
}

# Vet all VMs in the resource group
$VMs = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName

# Start each of the VMs
foreach ($VM in $VMs)
{   
    $StartRtn = $VM | Start-AzureRmVM -ErrorAction Continue

    if ($StartRtn.IsSuccessStatusCode -ne $True)
    {
        # The VM failed to start, so send notice
        Write-Output ($VM.Name + " failed to start")
        Write-Error ($VM.Name + " failed to start. Error was:") -ErrorAction Continue
        Write-Error (ConvertTo-Json $StartRtn) -ErrorAction Continue
    }
    else
    {
        # The VM stopped, so send notice
        Write-Output ($VM.Name + " has been started")
    }
}
```